# Author Filtering that have a meta_value that contains "yes" string

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

Meta Values:

```
$args = array(
'meta_key' => 'featuredservice03',
'meta_value' => 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Loop:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
foreach ( $user_query->results as $author ) {
   //code goes here.. 
}
```

Trying to get the loop to only show authors that have 'featuredservices03' value that have "yes" sub string. Would I have to serialize the meta_value?

Answer (score 0):

For example consider your meta_value are

```
 1. a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";} 
 2. a:2:{i:0;s:3:"no";i:1;s:6:"yes ok";}
```

Since your meta value is serialized, you have to search for the 'value' in the serialized string.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featuredservice03',
            'value'   => '%yes%',  // search with value
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Results :

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";} 
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"no";i:1;s:6:"yes ok";}
```

Or you can create a 'serialized value' that you want to search in meta value

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featuredservice03',
            'value'   => serialize( array( 'yes' ) ),  // search with serialized array
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Results :

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
```

Comment: hello, this unfortunately didnt solve my issue, i am trying to only show authors if they have the "yes" for that meta value.

Comment: what results you got? print_r($user_query->results);

Comment: all regular meta that authors have, does not include any custom user meta